# How do I adjust the search radius of places in Google Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

When sending a request I use the [parameter radius=300](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) which should show places within a radius of 300 meters from my location:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
stringBuilder.append("location=").append(mLatitude).append(",").append(mLongitude);
stringBuilder.append("&keyword=пятерочка | магнит");
stringBuilder.append("&language=ru");
stringBuilder.append("&radius=300");
stringBuilder.append("&sensor=true");
```

The same [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) at a value of 300 meters from my location:

```
Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(latLng)
        .radius(300).strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 0, 0))
        .fillColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 0, 0)));
```

The documentation says that the values are returned in meters that is in the request of 300 meters and in the Circle 300 meters but in fact I get this:

[image from my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRkMb.jpg)

Is it possible to make the radius displayed by the circle match the radius of the request?

P.S. I'm sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) documentation says that -

> Results inside of this region will be ranked higher than results
>   outside of the search circle; however, prominent results from outside
>   of the search radius may be included.

So, the conclusion is that some of the prominent location might be shown outside your defined radius. However, you can exclude those outside your boundary by implementing a loop after getting all results from the API.

1. Include Map-utils inside your dependencies -

> implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

2. Calculate distances from your centre for each place and place markers for those which are inside the boundary

```java
for (Place place: allPlaces) {
    float distance = (float) SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(centreLatLng, place.getLatLng());
    if (distance <= 300) {
        Marker placeMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(place.getLatLng())
            .title(place.getName())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .anchor(0.5 f, 1.0 f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation helped me. I did another because I already have distance. Just added such a loop to the method where the markers are redrawn: 
if (distance < radius){
                    markerOptions.title(name + " : " + distance + " метров");
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
Hence, markers beyond the radius are not added to the map!